# replace or remove special char from List<String> java

Tags: java, java-8

replace or remove special char from List java

```
List<String> somestring = ['%french', 
                           '@spanish', 
                           '!latin'];
```

How to remove the special characters and replace it with space.

```
List<String> somestring = ['%french', 
                           '@spanish', 
                           '!latin'];
somestring.replaceall('%','');
```

How to get this as result

```
List<String> somestring = ['french', 
                           'spanish', 
                           'latin'];
```

Answer (score 2):

First, **never** use a raw `List`. You have a `List<String>`. Second, a `String` literal (in Java) is surrounded by double quotes (`"`) not single quotes. Third, you can stream your `List<String>` and map the elements with a regular expression and collect them back to the original `List<String>`. Like,

```
List<String> somestring = Arrays.asList("%french", "@spanish", "!latin");
somestring = somestring.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\W", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(somestring);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
[french, spanish, latin]
```

Comment: I will suggest you go for regular expressions Search and Replace, using Pattern and Matcher Classes,  as in that way you have better control over the special characters you want to specify

Comment: The OP didn’t use raw types, but just poor formatting which hid the type parameters. Besides that, I’d rather use a simple `somestring.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceFirst("[%@!]", ""));` or perhaps, just  `somestring.replaceAll(s -> s.substring(1));`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class RegexMatches {
   private static String REGEX = "\\!|\\%|\\@"; //control on Special characters...
   private static String INPUT = "The %dog% says !meow. " + "!All @dogs @say meow.";
   private static String REPLACE = ""; //Replacement string

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
      //get a matcher object
      Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
      INPUT = m.replaceAll(REPLACE);
      System.out.println(INPUT);
   }
}
```

Added a sample snippet to explain the same, please extend to collections accordingly.

Comment: thanks for reply, the ask here is to have INPUT as List<String> and not the String shown in snippet.

Comment: yes, I shared how to do for a single String Input,  obviously, you need to iterate over the ArrayList and take every element (String) and apply the logic shared then  and push to another ArrayList as Strings are immutable, that's why I asked you to extend for collection

Comment: How to replace specific special characters $ or ! or & to space. any idea?

Comment: the above snippet already take care of "!" , for "$" for space 
(\\s+) update this private static String REGEX = "\\!|\\%|\\@|\\$|\\s+"; and add others specifall.

Comment: @Gold Win just append  "|\\&" to Regex string.